# When should we whitelist Community Cloud IP ranges?

Tags: community, security, community-cloud, experience-cloud, ip

As per the article [Salesforce IP Addresses and Domains to Allow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000321501&type=1&mode=1) :

> Recommended for seamless access: Our best practice is to allow our entire set of IP ranges. This is to ensure our login pools can process your end users’ and integrations’ login authentications when accessing Salesforce all over the world, and to avoid any unintended service disruptions due to movement between data center sites.

There is a section dedicated for Community Cloud IP Ranges in this same article, but the question is when should we allow/whitelist Community Cloud IP ranges ?

This question may sound opinion-based, but this just of better of collecting some facts and actual experience from the community

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it makes sense if you are an organization which allows outside connections to specific systems/IP's only and you need to allow access to experience cloud from your internal corporate network. It doesn't matter then if your experience is public or requires login as this feature is whitelisting IP's in other systems like a firewall not Salesforce.

I am assuming that external API calls via Salesforce (For community specific code) are made from Salesforce's IP Ranges, if they use Community Cloud IP ranges then the external systems need to whitelist these IP's as well..

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to provide your inputs